# Как протестировать декораторс с помошью Py.Test

Tags: python

Имеется декоратор. Он рабочий и выполняет то что нужно.
вопрос как написать тест для тестирования декоратора/декораторов на Py.Test ?

Декоратор

```
def background_worker(interval):
'''
Запускает декорированную функцию в 
отдельном потоке с задержкой в interval
''' 
def my_decorator(func):
    @wraps(func) # корректируем параметр __name__ у оборачиваемой функции
    def wrapper():
        # дополнительная функция на основании которой мы создадим поток
        def inner():
            while True:
                time.sleep(interval)
                func()
        # создаем настраивам и запускаем поток      
        t = threading.Thread(target=inner)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
    return wrapper
return my_decorator
```

вот пример его использования

```
@background_worker(10)
def some_job():
   print 'job',datetime.now()

some_job()
while True:
    pass
```

Т.е. в этом случае мы выполняем код как он будет выполняться в приложении
а вот как сделать тестирование декоратора в Py.test вот тут то и затык.

Comment: Вижу два варианта:

1. Написать функцию-жертву, которую обернуть вашим декоратором и функцию-жертву подать в тест.
2. Проэмулировать работу декоратора. Вы же знаете декоратор это ничто иное как синтаксический сахар.

Comment: так вот на этапе подачи в тест и возникает вопрос. к примеру у нас есть декоратор bg_worker который запускает в потоке оборачиваему функцию с задержкой в n - секунд. просто сделать модуль с обернутой функцией выводящей время в консоль не проблемма. а вот с написанием теста затык.

Comment: Давайте не будем гадать по кофейной гуще и напишем немного коду? Напишите, что имеется и как примерно должно выглядетЬ, хотя бы в виде псевдкода.